# How to search data from textbox and fill specific columns of datagridview from SQL database?

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I am trying to search itemcode by typing in textbox and i want to get specific columns in same row from SQL database. I have made columns with headers in datagridview and i want that searched data in that specific datagridview columns.  I have written code but it's not working. I do not know how to do this. I am new and trying to learn vb. Please give some suggestion.

This is my code:

```
Private Sub Button13_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button13.Click

    Using cn As New SqlConnection("server= PANKAJ\SQLEXPRESS; database = pankaj billing software; integrated security=true")
        Using cmd2 As New SqlCommand("select itemcode As 'Item Code', item,qty As Quantity, weight as Weight from stockdata Where itemcode = @itemcode;", cn)
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemcode", TextBox1.Text)
            cn.Open()
            Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader()
            dt.Load(dr)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dt



            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows


                cmd2.Parameters.Add("@item", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                cmd2.Parameters.Add("@qty", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                cmd2.Parameters.Add("@weight", SqlDbType.VarChar)


                With cmd2

                    row.Cells(1).Value = .Parameters("@item").Value
                    row.Cells(2).Value = .Parameters("@qty").Value
                    row.Cells(2).Value = .Parameters("@weight").Value
                End With
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: That is not a valid SQL select statement; start by getting the basic SQL syntax correct. Then work on how many parameters you need in the statement, and how to provide them.

Comment: Can you tell me how to correct this code?

Comment: `CellLeave` is the wrong event to handle. You should be handling `CellValueChanged`. As for the SQL, you don't need us to tell you what to do when it's so easy to find information for yourself. Do some reading on SQL syntax. As it is, you have half a `SELECT` and half an `INSERT`. If you can read, you can find out how to write a proper `SELECT` statement. That's basic stuff that you shouldn't need us to teach you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a TextBox located outside the DataGridView to enter the item code to search for. I added a Button to do the search and retrieve the data to a DataReader.

The DataReader then loads the DataTable which is declared as a form level (class level variable). We want to use the same DataTable every time we search so the items will be added to the grid. With the Load method if the DataTable already contains rows, the incoming data from the data source is merged with the existing rows. The DataTable is then bound to the DataGridView. Each time the user enters an item code in the TextBox and clicks the Search Button a new row will be added to the grid.

To make nicer looking Column headers use as alias in your Select statement. The As clause following the databse column name is the alias and will show up in the DataGridView as a header. If you have a space in your alias it must be enclosed in single quotes.

```
Private dt As DataTable

Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    dt = New DataTable()
End Sub

Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("server= PANKAJ\SQLEXPRESS; database = pankaj billing software; integrated security=true")
        Using cmd2 As New SqlCommand("select itemcode As 'Item Code', item,qty As Quantity, weight as Weight from stockdata Where itemcode = @itemcode;", cn)
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemcode", txtItemCode.Text)
            cn.Open()
            Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader()
            dt.Load(dr)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

P.S. Very glad to see the use of parameters and Using blocks! :-)

Comment: i have already made coloums in datagridview so when i search all this data by textbox it should be in specific cell or coloum of datagridview.

Answer (score 1):

I saw several things to check:

- When you use a datasource, you don't need to loop through the rows of your reader.
- Check the connection string (is "pankaj billing software" *really* the name of the database? They don't usually have spaces)
- You want square brackets (`[]` or double quotes `"`) rather than single quotes (`'`) for the column name in the SQL statement.
- It's also best to avoid the `AddWithValue()` function in favor of calling `Add()` with the exact column type and length.
- We don't see where `dt` is declared.

Put it all together (guessing at column name/length, and haven't changed the database name yet) and you get this:

```
Private Sub Button13_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button13.Click
    Dim sql = "select itemcode As [Item Code], item, qty As Quantity, weight as Weight from stockdata Where itemcode = @itemcode;"
    Dim dt As New DataTable()

    Using cn As New SqlConnection("server=PANKAJ\SQLEXPRESS;database=pankaj billing software;integrated security=true"), _
         cmd2 As New SqlCommand(sql, cn)
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@itemcode", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value = TextBox1.Text
        cn.Open()

        Using dr As SqlDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader()
            dt.Load(dr)
        End Using
    End Using

    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

But the big thing is "Not working" in **never** enough information about your code. What did you actually see that was different than what you expected? If there was an error message, what did it say exactly?

Answer (score 0):

This is my script code:

```
protected void search_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(conn);
    if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    sqlCon.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spSearchUser", sqlCon);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchTerm", "username");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtSearch.Text);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
      dr.Read();
      searchBind();
      GridView1.Visible = true;
      txtSearch.Text = "";
    }
  }
```

This is WebForm code:

```
   <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Search</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Go" onclick="search_click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  runat="server"></asp:GridView>
    </div>
```

This is my Store Procedure:

```
   alter procedure spSearchUser
   (
      @SearchTerm nvarchar(50),
      @Username nvarchar(50)
   )
   as
   begin
     set nocount on;
     if @SearchTerm = 'username'
     begin
       select Username,City,Gender,Email from tblRegistration where Username 
       LIKE '%' + @Username + '%'
     end
   end
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

```
'"C:\your_path\Northwind.mdb"
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class Form1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    Private bindingSource1 As New BindingSource()
    Private dataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter()

    <STAThreadAttribute()> _
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Application.Run(New Form1())
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\your_path\Northwind.mdb"
        Dim selectCommand As String
        Dim connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)

        selectCommand = "Select * From MyExcelTable ORDER BY ID"
        Me.dataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(selectCommand, connection)

        With DataGridView1
            .AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells
            .AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.ColumnHeader
            .AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.ColumnHeader
        End With

        Dim commandBuilder As New OleDbCommandBuilder(Me.dataAdapter)
        Dim table As New DataTable()

        table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

        Me.dataAdapter.Fill(table)
        Me.bindingSource1.DataSource = table

        Dim data As New DataSet()

        data.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

        DataGridView1.DataSource = Me.bindingSource1
        Me.DataGridView1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Aqua
        Me.DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns( _
            DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, btnUpdate.Click
        Dim table As New DataTable()

        Me.bindingSource1 = Me.DataGridView1.DataSource
        table = Me.bindingSource1.DataSource

        Me.dataAdapter.Update(table)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click, btnClose.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged, TextBox1.Click

        Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\your_path\Northwind.mdb"
        Dim selectCommand As String
        Dim connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)

        'selectCommand = "Select * From MyExcelTable where Fname = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
        '"SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Address LIKE '" & strAddressSearch & "%'"
        'or ending with:
        '"SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Address LIKE '%" & strAddressSearch & "'"

        selectCommand = "Select * From MyExcelTable where Fname Like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"
        Me.dataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(selectCommand, connection)

        With DataGridView1
            .AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells
            .AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.ColumnHeader
            .AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.ColumnHeader
        End With

        Dim commandBuilder As New OleDbCommandBuilder(Me.dataAdapter)
        Dim table As New DataTable()

        table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

        Me.dataAdapter.Fill(table)
        Me.bindingSource1.DataSource = table

        Dim data As New DataSet()

        data.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

        DataGridView1.DataSource = Me.bindingSource1
        Me.DataGridView1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Aqua
        Me.DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns( _
            DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells)

    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]